# Email still sending and data captured even using return

Tags: node.js

I am verifying a reCaptcha token and purposefully making it fail for testing. I can see in console that I am getting the error I return but the email is still sending and the form data is still being captured in the database. I thought that since I am using return it would stop everything in its tracks and not send the email/write to database?

```
  request(verifyUrl, (error, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(body);
    if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: "Failed captcha verification" });
    }
  });

  let contact = new Contact({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    comments: comments,
  });
  contact = await contact.save();

// send email code
```

I tried doing an if else but get errors about not being an async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an async call. The callback that you are passing to request will be executed only after the whole body of the function, including the contact creation is executed.

```
request(verifyUrl, async (error, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(body);
    if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: "Failed captcha verification" });
    }

    let contact = new Contact({
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      email: email,
      comments: comments,
    });
    contact = await contact.save();
  });
```

You need to move contact creation to the callback if you want to block it by that return statement.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and the error I get is `SyntaxError await is only valid in async function`

Comment: check the answer, you are missing `async` keyword in front of the callback